# Predicted class along with its corresponding probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I have built a machine learning model using maxvoting(Decision tree, Random Forest, Logistic Regression) classifier. For which i have have the input as

**{
"Salary": 50000, 
"Current loans": 15000,
"Credit Score": 616,
"Requested Loan": 25000
}**

When i pass this data to my model. It is giving the prediction as

**{"Status": Approve}**

But i need to retrieve the response like

**{"Status": Approve, "Accuracy": 0.87}**

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you want to take a look at [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're probably using sklearn's [`VotingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html). Once you've fitted the classifier, you see the probabilities associated with each class through the attribute [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.predict_proba). Note that rather than an accuracy, this is really the associated probability of each class. So if you want the probability of a test sample being of class `n`, you'll have to index the output `y_pred_prob` on the corresponding column. Here's an example using sklearn's iris dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

clf1 = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', random_state=1)
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=1)
clf3 = GaussianNB()

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

eclf2 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2), ('gnb', clf3)],
        voting='soft')

eclf2 = eclf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And we could get the probabilities associated to the first class for instance with:

```
eclf2.predict_proba(X_test)[:,0].round(2)

array([0.99, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.01, 0.01, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ,
       0.99, 0.  , 0.99, 0.99, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ,
       0.  , 0.01, 0.98, 0.  , 1.  , 0.99, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.99, 0.98,
       0.  , 0.99, 0.  , 0.01, 0.99])
```

Finally, to get an output as you've described, you can use the result returned by `predict`, to index the 2D probability array as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

y_pred = eclf2.predict(X_test)
y_pred_prob = eclf2.predict_proba(X_test).round(2)
associated_prob = y_pred_prob[np.arange(len(y_test)), y_pred]
pd.DataFrame({'class':y_pred, 'Accuracy':associated_prob})

    class  Accuracy
0       0      0.99
1       2      0.84
2       2      1.00
3       1      0.95
4       2      0.99
5       2      0.91
6       1      0.98
7       1      0.98
8       1      0.93
```

Or if you prefer the output as a dictionary:

```
pd.DataFrame({'class':y_pred, 'Accuracy':associated_prob}).to_dict(orient='index')

 {0: {'class': 0, 'Accuracy': 0.99},
  1: {'class': 2, 'Accuracy': 0.84},
  2: {'class': 2, 'Accuracy': 1.0},
  3: {'class': 1, 'Accuracy': 0.95},
  4: {'class': 2, 'Accuracy': 0.99},
```

Comment: I have tried the same exaple which you provided. but throwing error at                                  import pandas  y_pred = eclf2.predict(X_test)
associated_prob = y_pred_prob[np.arange(len(y_test)), y_pred]
pd.DataFrame({'class':y_pred, 'Accuracy':associated_prob})

Comment: Try now see if it works @syedjameer I was missing the definition of `y_pred_prob `

Comment: Thanks it help me @yatu

Comment: Dear @yatu 
I'm Trying to implement the same scenario using Decision tree. Facing the same problem. Please can you help me. How to get the accuracy value while using decision tree. It would be more helpful